# Bash: sourcing file executes code enclosed in quotes

Tags: string, bash, config

i have a bash script which takes in input some options and behaves accordingly.
One of the options read variables in a config file (if it exists). Though with that option and only that option it also prints out

```
.shelter: line 2127: /usr/bin/install: Argument list too long
```

on top of everything.
Below is the code between the recognition of the option and the next output (which works fine):

```
...
if [ "$1" = "status" ] ; then #1
if [[ -f .shelter ]] ; then  #2
    source .shelter
    if [ "$SHELTER" = "git" ] ; then #3
        echo "Shelter:  git"
    else 
        if [ "$SHELTER" = "bunker" ] ; then #4
            echo "Shelter: bunker"
        else 
            echo "Shelter: not set"
        fi #-4
    fi #-3
   
...
```

The error gets printed before `Shelter:` but it doesn't appear with any other option, so it has to be below `if [ "$1" = "status" ] ; then #1`

*How the script should work:*

> The scripts when asked creates a file containing some variables it takes from files around the project. When user asks those variables are used to fill those same files. This means that variables content and files content must be the exact same all the time, i thought that copying in and copying out would have done exactly that. I was wrong

*Considerations:*

Line 2127 is this `"deprecated": "Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'"` so I thought it might be something with quotes, but that part isn't even used where it prints the error out.
My other option was the testing of the .shelter file, but i don't see why it would need to operate with the content of the file just to check its existence.
Is there a way to force the script to treat every single character of the variables as they are (like some automatic backslasher or some "these are all chars" nuclear option)? Or maybe some other way to check wether the file exists or not? Or maybe even something i missed out?

If you need any more information or have suggestions not regarding the question let me know in the comments.

**EDIT:**

i think i need to be more specific. The file `.shelter` has no code inside. it looks like this

```
SHELTER='stuff'
PACKAGE='otherstuff'
```

the stuff it contains are plainly copied from json files, and outputted as strings in the .shelter file.

Line 2127 is an error message, but just because it has been copied from the other file. I really don't care what's inside the files i'm getting info from, I just need plain text as it is and return it as it is.

Also yes, the .shelter file is autogenerated, but autogeneration can't output any errors in the file.

The line that gives me problem is just a piece of some json string that probably states what npm has to output if the package is deprecated.

**EDIT-2:**

*Lines from 2120 to 2140 of .shelter:*

```
      "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/sindresorhus"
  }
},
"node_modules/@hapi/address": {
  "version": "2.1.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@hapi/address/-/address-2.1.4.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-QD1PhQk+s31P1ixsX0H0Suoupp3VMXzIVMSwobR3F3MSUO2YCV0B7xqLcUw/Bh8yuvd3LhpyqLQWTNcRmp6IdQ==",
  "deprecated": "Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'"
},
"node_modules/@hapi/bourne": {
  "version": "1.3.2",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@hapi/bourne/-/bourne-1.3.2.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-1dVNHT76Uu5N3eJNTYcvxee+jzX4Z9lfciqRRHCU27ihbUcYi+iSc2iml5Ke1LXe1SyJCLA0+14Jh4tXJgOppA==",
  "deprecated": "This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained"
},
"node_modules/@hapi/hoek": {
  "version": "8.5.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@hapi/hoek/-/hoek-8.5.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-yN7kbciD87WzLGc5539Tn0sApjyiGHAJgKvG9W8C7O+6c7qmoQMfVs0W4bX17eqz6C78QJqqFrtgdK5EWf6Qow==",
  "deprecated": "This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained"
},
```

Comment: Error is inside your `.shelter` code, not here.

Comment: @anubhava .shelter has **no code** as i said. It's just a file containing text

Comment: while processing `source .shelter` an error is found at `line 2127`; first question would be: `what's at line 2127 of .shelter?` problem is that if other files are being sourced, or functions called, this line number (`2127`) isn't necessarily from `.shelter`; the error message also mentions `/usr/bin/install` ... can you find any code (in `.shelter`, in other files sourced by `.shelter`, possibly in functions called during the `source`) that perform an `install`? you may also want to consider `set -xv` prior to `source .shelter` to get more details (caution; will create a lot of output)

Comment: you've stated `Line 2127 is this "deprecated": "Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'"` but this itself is an error message and, by itself, not something that would be `sourced`; if this line is part of a bigger piece of code (in `.shelter`) then we'd need to see the entire piece of code to establish context; on the other hand ...

Comment: you've also stated `scripts ... creates a file containing some variables`, which sounds like something auto-generated the `.shelter` file and `source .shelter` is being used to load these 'variables' into the environment; if this is the case, what you've posted as the contents of `line 2127` (an error message) seems to indicate an error in the auto-generation of `.shelter` (ie, `.shelter` contains jibberish) which in turn means any attempt to `source .shelter` is going to be fraught with errors, so the first step would be to review the contents of `.shelter` for accuracy

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you for the `set -xv` advice, that's really useful. I have also edited the question with new info

Comment: @FabioR. If `.shelter` has no code and contains only text, then what do you think `source .shelter` actually does? Those assignments *are* code.

Comment: @FabioR : Why do you execute `.shelter` as code, if it doesn't have any? I suggest that you turn on tracign with `set -x` before running `source .shelter`. Or you delete the whole line if you think it should not be executed.

Comment: @chepner yes, that's code, but if i say `VAR="cd inexistent_folder"` then `$VAR` is equal to `"cat inexistent_folder"`, not to `"no such file or directory"`, is it? In this case `"cd foo"` would be text, not code

Comment: If you were to set `VAR` to that value, then simply type `$VAR` at the prompt, the "text" *will* be interpreted as a command after word-splitting has been applied to the expansion. *Something* in `.shelter` is doing more than simply assigning values to variables.

Comment: You can't expect us to debug code that we can't see.  Either `.shelter` has code that produces that error, or your autogeneration is not as infallible as you believe.

Comment: @chepner gosh, I didn't ask to debug anything (quoting from my question: "is there a way to force the script to treat every single character of the variables as they are? Or maybe some other way to check wether the file exists or not?"). Anyway, I'm pasting you the whole `.shelter` without variable content (too long) so you can see the "code" doing more than assigning. `SHELTER=bunker
PACKAGE='' LOCK='' MANAGER=npm` (they are all on a newline), that's all

Comment: you've confirmed `Line 2127 is an error message` and then you mention `but autogeneration can't output any errors in the file` which is a contradiction ... how'd the error message get into line 2127 if the autogeneration can't output any errors ???? regardless, the `source .shelter` command processes each line as a command so when it gets to line 2127 it tries to 'execute' the error message which of course is itself an invalid command and thus generates its own error

Comment: @markp-fuso the file is autogenerated because no one writes a single line, but this doesn't mean that it has error output, that's something i should have implemented for that to happen. This is a copy n paste of text, that same line is identical in the other file I got it from, it's not an error from the generation, it's just a default message of the app i'm taking text from, but it has nothing to do with me, i didn't write that, it came from another pregenerated file

Comment: @markp-fuso so you are telling me that it's not possible to source a string variable built on more lines?

Comment: please update the question with lines 2120-2140 of `.shelter`

Comment: ok, so now we know you've got a chunk of json data in `.shelter` ... what's the command that's processing this `json` data, ie, what's at the beginning of the block of `json` data?; if the entire file is just `json` data ... you don't `source` a `json` data file but rather process it with a program (eg, `jq`); is there a `jq` call in `.shelter`?

Comment: @markp-fuso if you mean inside my script then it's `echo "PACKAGE='$(cat package.json)'" >> .shelter`. This should append file content to `PACKAGE=` and then append everything to .shelter, am i right? Moreover if i `echo '""'` it sould output `""`, right?

Comment: @markp-fuso nono, there is literally no code at all inside .shelter. Just variable assignments, from start to end. I just need it to store strings, not as some library

Comment: Whether or not you consider `.shelter` to be code is irrelevant. `source .shelter` executes the content of `.shelter` as if it were code. Since assignments are code, this may work, but somewhere in `.shelter` you have an actual command, probably due to wrong quoting.

Comment: `PACKAGE='$(cat package.json)'"` is going to generate `PACKAGE="...lots_of_embedded_single_and_double_quotes..."` which is going to lead to parsing issues when running `source`; based on error messages I'm guessing this piece of text (or simiilar) - `npm install @sideway/address` - has been parsed and **a)** not considered as part of a string but **b)** considered as an actual command to be run by `source`, and the follow-on `'"....."` (ie mis-parsed data) is being interpreted as a really long set of quoted arguments to `install`

Comment: `echo "PACKAGE='$(cat package.json)'" >> .shelter` will create a syntax error and possibly unpredictable side effects if `package.json` contains a single quote somewhere.

Comment: @tripleee exactly, we can see the following line in the snippet provided by OP: `"Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'"`; a pair of single quotes pulls `npm install @sideways/address` out as a command and the follow-on strings as arguments

Comment: `x='ABC' echo "def" 'HIJ'` => variable `x` is set to `'ABC'` and `def HIJ` is sent to stdout (ie, `"def" 'HIJ'` treated as args to `echo`)

Comment: @markp-fuso thank you, so it really was some quoting issue. Going back to the original question: is there any way to force him to treat whatever is contained inside the variable to be treated as a char and not a quote or do i have to loop through the whole config file and put  `\` whenever i see a quote?

Comment: see my answer; `tl:dr` ... don't have the `cat` executed during the creation of `.shelter` but have the `cat` executed during the `source .shelter` (though follow-on issues for the `PACKAGE` variable may occur ...); as for some method of 'properly parsing' the current (problem-prone) `.shelter` ... nothing easy comes to mind ... certainly not something the basic `source` is going to be able to handle; best bet is to go back and modify the code that generates `.shelter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an extended back-n-forth in comments we have:

- `.shelter` is autogenerated by other scripting code
- `.shelter` contains a list of variable assignments
- one of the commands used to populate `.shelter` is `echo "PACKAGE='$(cat package.json)'"` but ...
- because of the outer quotes the `cat` is executed and the results are dumped into `.shelter` leading to the following being placed in '.shelter` ...
- `PACKAGE='".... bunch of json data ... "Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'"...'` with the internal single quotes causing problems during parsing thus leading to ...
- `npm install @sidway/address'"...'` being processed as a command and not as part of the `PACKAGE='...'` assignment

If the objective is to have the `PACKAGE` variable populated during the `source .shelter` then this:

```
echo "PACKAGE='$(cat package.json)'" >> .shelter     # outer double quotes causes the 'cat' command to be executed and the results dumped into .shelter
```

should be replaced with:

```
echo 'PACKAGE=$(cat package.json)' >> .shelter       # single quotes means no call to 'cat' and the entire line is written as a string into .shelter
```

Now when `source .shelter` is run the following happens:

```
PACKAGE=$(cat package.json)                          # at this point 'cat' is called and the results are stored in the 'PACKAGE' variable
```

Granted, from here OP's script may have problems parsing the contents of `PACKAGE` due to embedded single/double quotes, but that's an issue for the next Q&A (eg, OP's script may benefit from a rewrite that uses a json-aware tool (eg, `jq`) to parse the `package.json` data into usable variables).

Comment: In case `source .shelter` has no acces to `package.json` anymore, you can use `printf 'PACKAGE=%q\n' "$(cat package.json)" >> .shelter` to safely embed the whole file.